# If $a<\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}<b\,\,(n>1),$ then which of the following options is correct?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck with the following problem that says :

> If $$a<\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}<b\,\,(n>1),$$ then
>
> 1. $a=1,b=\pi/3$
> 2. $a=1/2,b=\pi/6$
> 3. $a=1,b=\pi/6$
> 4. None of these

I was thinking along the line : Since $x \in (0,1),\,\,1-x^{2n}<1 \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}>1 \implies \int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}>1$. So,$a=1$ but I am not sure how to find $b$.

But the answer key to the problem says option 2 is the correct choice.

Comment: Not a complete answer but might start you off: for $x\in[0,1]$

$$x^2>x^{2n}\\
1-x^2<1-x^{2n}\\
\frac{1}{1-x^2}>\frac{1}{1-x^{2n}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}$$

integral of left is $sin^{-1}x$ which has the value $\pi/2$ in this case. Not sure how to find the better bound

Comment: Thanks sachin for your interest to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The bounds are $\bigg[1,\dfrac\pi2\bigg]$, since $x^{2n}\in[0,x^2]$ for $x\in[0,1]$ with $n>1$.

Comment: For me, the bounds are $1$ and $\pi/3$.

Comment: For values of *n* very close to $1$ we have values of the integral very close to $\dfrac\pi2$. And if *n* is meant to be natural, the upper bound would still not be $\dfrac\pi3$, but rather $\sqrt\pi\cdot\dfrac{(1/4)!}{(-1/4)!}$ .